# Can you make a script list all editable fields of a component without making it a custom editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game where UI elements change based on the time of day. There are 3 different times and I'd like to make it so that you have three foldout menus where you modify the component(s) but it only applies at their specified time of day. Right now I have it so that the three foldout menus open to custom editors that all do the same thing.

[Foldout Menus Closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXU3y.png) [Foldout Menus Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dg1P.png)

Ideally, I could get rid of the custom editors all-together, and just have the editor script list all editable fields of the listed component. Then I could just feed those fields back into the original component depending on the time of day. I can't for the life of me find any way of doing this even though it seems fairly simple. Essentially, I want it to look like the above images without the editable fields modifying the object.

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Component[] timeComponent;
}
```

Script Editor:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(TimeScript))]
public class TimeScriptEditor : Editor
{
    private bool showDay = false;
    private bool showNight = false;
    private bool showMystery = false;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();
        TimeScript currScript = (TimeScript)target;

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        showDay = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showDay, "Day", true, EditorStyles.foldout);

        if (showDay) // Displays code only if you click the foldout
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currScript.timeComponent.Length; i++) // Displays custom editor for every component in the array
            {
                int currNum = i + 1;
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Component " + currNum + ":");
                CreateEditor(currScript.timeComponent[i]).OnInspectorGUI(); // Creates custom editor for selected component
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        showNight = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showNight, "Night", true, EditorStyles.foldout);

        if (showNight) // Displays code only if you click the foldout
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currScript.timeComponent.Length; i++) // Displays custom editor for every component in the array
            {
                int currNum = i + 1;
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Component " + currNum + ":");
                CreateEditor(currScript.timeComponent[i]).OnInspectorGUI(); // Creates custom editor for selected component
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        showMystery = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(showMystery, "Mystery", true, EditorStyles.foldout);

        if (showMystery) // Displays code only if you click the foldout
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < currScript.timeComponent.Length; i++) // Displays custom editor for every component in the array
            {
                int currNum = i + 1;
                EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Component " + currNum + ":");
                CreateEditor(currScript.timeComponent[i]).OnInspectorGUI(); // Creates custom editor for selected component
            }
        }
    }
}
```